# VB Script Global Scope DIM Statement - Concurrency

Tags: vbscript

I am writing an utility VB Script for FTP functionality and accepting the server details (host, user and password) as command line arguments. It is possible that same VB Script can be called at the same time from two different parent jobs for FTP operations.

My question is, in this case where same VB Script called concurrently, would there be a chance of DIM variable collision defined in global scope or command line variable collision.

If the 'answer' is yes. could you please let me know, is there a way to avoid this collision.

Comment: No, they are two completely separate scripts running in their own Windows Scripting Host processes. The global scope is only global within its parent process, they cannot collide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

---

A script runs inside a host process. Commonly this process is the `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe` both known as the Windows Scripting Host. Whenever you execute a script an individual host process is started and this is where the global scope of the script lives, any subsequent scripts have their own host process and global scope.

Because of this, there is no chance of the global scope in multiple scripts colliding.

It's quite easy to test, create two scripts with the same `Public` variables and see if one can affect the other. That way you could answer your own question.